# Greater than Conditional Formatting using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Hello I get some data from website using custom function with an XMLHTTP request now I need to apply some formatting condition to copied data and  I would appreciate some advice  using VBA :

The active cell "B" column

Less than 10  red 
Between 10 and 15 yellow 
More than 15 green

all the cell not returning any number should be  blank

THX

Comment: Have you tried applying that formatting manually while using the macro recorder?

Comment: You can use conditional formatting without recurring to VBA.

Comment: I tried to  use macro record but is not working as I need it  because  colors also the empty cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

### The easy way:

Use Excel built-in conditional formatting (Select your range and click **Home** tab > **Conditional Formatting** > Add a **rule** or choose from the default rules -*I think it has extensive options enough for your needs.*)

[image]

### The philosophical way:

Add a new module from your VBA IDE.

Copy and paste this code:

```
 Sub ColorRange()
Dim d as Double
Dim r As Range
Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B500")
For Cell in r
If Cell.Text <> "" And IsNumeric(Cell.Value) = True Then
If Cell.Text < 10 Then
Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
ElseIf Cell.Text >= 10 And Cell.Text <= 15 Then
Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
Else
Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
End If
End If
Next
End Sub
```

and run the macro.

Here's an output sample:
[image]

### Which one I recommend?

I would recommend you use **conditional formatting**, no need for the VBA magic if the good old built-in Excel features can handle it, unless your need prove otherwise.

Comment: But it doesn't work with B column as I copy some data from website with "=giveMeValue(A1)"

Comment: The data has to be a double datatype otherwise it won't work.

Comment: ok ...but if I have to make it bouble datatype   and I use B1=A1 for example to copy the  value it doesn't work anyway

Comment: Can you do `debug.print(Range("B5") & " " & Typename(Range("B5").Value) & " " & Range("B5").Text)` with B5 (for example) just to see what you got there.

Comment: this is what return on "B5"    19 String 19

Comment: That's what I reckoned, your XML parsing return is a string when it should be double since you're dealing with number or long. Give a try now and let if it works.

Comment: now is working but is cancelling the formula "=giveMeValue(A1)" and print just number , in this case next time I re-open the sile I will not able to check the availabilities anymore

Comment: Is returning error "unable to set text property of range class" on 'Cell.Text = CDbl(Cell.Text)'

Comment: Sorry would you try it now.

Comment: from my side doesn't return any color

Comment: I guess I solved with macro and seems to do the job :

`Dim color As Integer

 For Each cell In Sheets(1).Range("B1:F65536")


    If IsEmpty(cell) Then GoTo nextcell:
    If Not IsNumeric(cell.Value) Then GoTo nextcell:


    If cell.Value > 14 Then
      color = 4
    ElseIf cell.Value < 8 Then color = 3
    Else: color = 6
    End If
    cell.Interior.ColorIndex = color
nextcell:
  Next cell


End Sub`

Any code advice  for button to update all the link " GiveMeValue(A1) "?